# How can I convert single user database application to multiuser?

Tags: database-design

My database holds three table *drugs*(contains drug information) , *sale*(contain sales information) , *purchase*(contains purchase information) for a single user(for a single shop).

How can I convert my database into multiuser database (for multiple shop).

And what is the good practice for multiuser database?

Comment: What do you mean by " a single user"?

Comment: Please, try to improve your question.

Answer (score 2):

Well, for starters, you'd probably want to add a `shop` table, and make sure that any information that applies to a specific shop includes the primary id for that table (let's call it `shop_id`).

That would probably at least be `sale` and `purchase`; if `drugs` includes inventory data (how many tablets/tubes/whatever the shop has of each drug), then it would need `shop_id` as well.

Whenever expanding a database design to allow for multiples of an object that there was only one of before, need to consider:

- What critical data needs to be stored for each instance of this object;
- Where data is stored for the current single instance of the object (In some cases the name of the shop might be hardcoded into data in some other table; in others, it might be hardcoded into the application);
- Where and how the data for the new multiple object should be stored (answer will almost always be in its own table, but do think about it);
- How data in existing tables may need to change or be rearranged for the multiple object (answer will usually be some variation on what was said above; data that would tied to specific instances of the new object will normally need to have the ID for a specific instance of the object added to each row).

In addition, when expanding like this, you should revisit the initial requirements for the system, and see if anything else should change. As an example: the shop that's been using the system might be run by one person, while the two new shops might have multiple people taking or fulfilling orders. If so, you might need an `employee` table, so you can identify who took made each sale or purchase.

Now: in database terms, "single-user" and "multi-user" generally mean how many people are actually using the system. If, up until now, there has only been one person actually using the database at any given time, and going forward there will be multiple people using the database at the same time (presumably, there will be at least one user in each shop), then you need to watch for problems in your code.

First, you need to be sure that your database allows multiple users at the same time. Also, you need to be sure that your infrastructure allows this: if your users all need to have access to the same file at the same time, you need to be sure that all can be connected to a common network, and that all have the necessary access to that file.

Second, you need to make sure that your system will behave as expected when multiple people are hitting it at the same time. For instance, if only one person is using the system, you might be setting a unique ID for each sale by getting the highest current sale ID when the application starts up, and simply adding one to that each time you create a new record. If two people are running the application that connects to you database, then each application might see that the maximum sale ID in the morning is 127. However, when the first user enters a new sale, there will now be a sale with ID 128; if the second user then tries to enter a sale without the application checking for the highest sale ID, they're also going to try to create a sale with the ID of 128. Assuming the sale ID field is properly configured as a primary key (or, at least requires unique values), this won't work. Most (if not all) databases provide some mechanism for providing new IDs (for instance, defining an integer column as an IDENTITY column will automatically assign a new sequential integer value to that column for each new record).

Look for information on "transactions" in your database system of choices; this is a mechanism to ensure that all changes to the database made in a sequence of commands are visible to others only once the sequence is complete. Transactions also ensure that, if there's an error in the third command in your sequence, the changes made by the first and second commands can be aborted ("rolled back"), leaving things as they were before your transaction started; however, that's applicable even if only one person is using the system.

If this is the sort of thing you're thinking about, then there are more things to consider than can be reasonably covered in a post like this. Check the documentation for your database system for information on multi-user systems; search the internet for more detail on designs and considerations for multi-user systems; and, be prepared for things to possibly go wrong.